# Pyplot have to run cell twice to set font size

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, font-size

Here is a single block of python code for Jupyter notebook:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 14
plt.plot([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
```

When I run it once, the text will be small (default) - bad.
Only when I run the same cell a second time on the same running kernel, the font will be larger (14 pt) as intended.

I am so confused, anyone know what's going on???

Comment: Usually when you have to run a code twice to see an effect, this mean that one of the commands occurred too late. You probably just have to move one line of code up. Which one? Difficult to say without a fully reproducible example, the above code sets the size correctly in one run.

Comment: The code sets the size correctly for me, OP please include a reproducible example.

Comment: If I separate into individual cells it is the same problem. Like IDK how to make a reproducible sample for you lol, when I run this it gives the problem - maybe it's something with how my environment is setup?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a proper solution, but adding `%matplotlib inline` at the top cell of my notebook solved the issue